# jquery attribute manipulation(DOM manipulation) for input type text not working?

Tags: jquery

in javascript below, variable **temp** would hold html string like this,

```
<input type="text" value="initial text" name="msg" />
```

why this code

```
$('input[name=msg]').val('hello world');
```

won't change html string to

```
<input type="text" value="hello world" name="msg" />
```

here is the code,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form><input type="text" value="initial text" name="msg" /></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function(){
        $('input[name=msg]').val('hello world');

        var temp = $('form').html();

        console.debug(temp);        
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

updated

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="foo" name="msg1" />
    <input type="text" value="bar" name="msg2" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('input[name=msg1]').val('hello world 1'); // this manipulates dom at html level
        $('input[name=msg2]').val('hello world 2'); // this does not! why?

        $('form').html();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

An element's HTML isn't the same as what its DOM properties are, that's just how it is.  Though your [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) style is deprecated, it's not the issue.  If you do this, you'll see the correct value:

```
console.debug($('input[name=msg]').val()); //"hello world"
console.debug($('form').serialize()); //"msg=hello+world"
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QuaQw/):

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=msg]').val('hello world');
  var temp = $('form').html();

  console.debug($('input[name=msg]').val()); //"hello world"
  console.debug($('form').serialize());      //"msg=hello+world"
  console.debug(temp);                       //"<input type="text" value="initial text" name="msg">"
});
```

Comment: @user443095 - it depends on the browser as to exactly what's rendered, but think of it this way, HTML is what the browser uses to create the DOM, after that they're not as strongly (1:1) connected as many thing, the DOM can be manipulated in many ways you won't see in the html output.

Comment: ok so DOM and HTML isn't same.
but I don't understand this, if I had used <input type="hidden"> this would have resulted with modified `value` attribute in html as well as dom. now why this works for hidden type but not text type ??

Comment: @Nikc, i see ok.. thanx a lot Nick, helped a lot

Comment: @user443095 - It just depends on the browser, some will show an updated value for both...this behavior isn't explicitly specified, so it's implementation (browser) dependent.